# Operation invalid when trying to open Recordset from SQL linked Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to open to a recordset of a linked table but i keep getting invalid operation error. it works fine with local table.

I have tried  to remove dbOpenTable but the error changed to 'Operation is not supported for this type of object'

It is important to note that i have a very shallow knowledge of vba access.
I would really appreciate any help I can get from this forum

```vb
Dim db As DAO. Database
Dim rst As Recordset

Set db=CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("myTable",dbOpenTable)

rst.Index = "PRODUCT_CODE"
rst.Seek "=", Me!Combo_Product_number


If Nz(Me!Combo_Product_number) = "" Then

DoCmd.OpenForm "Not_found_Inventory"

ElseIf rst.NoMatch Then

DoCmd.OpenForm "Not_found_Inventory"

Else
 DoCmd.OpenForm "FRM_Inventory_A01", WhereCondition:="[PRODUCT_CODE]='" & Me!Combo_Product_number & "'"

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Seek` method is only valid on a table local to the opened database.

Use the `FindFirst` method on a linked table.

Comment: I tried to replace the seek syntax wih FindFirst as shown: Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("T_DOSSIER_Inventory")
strCriteria = “PRODUCT_CODE = ” & Me!Combo_Product_number
rst.FindFirst (strCriteria)                        but the strCriteria is not funtioning as i cant seem to find any match

Comment: If the "number" is text, you need quotes: `strCriteria = "PRODUCT_CODE = '" & Me!Combo_Product_number & "'"`. And the double-quotes must be real double-quotes, no smart quotes.